# Elasticsearch: Full text search

Tags: elasticsearch, full-text-search

I'm trying to build an Elasticsearch full-text search query with the following text "Gold Cartier watches" on multiple fields.

I have to follow this rule: First find all "Gold" documents. From retrieve "Gold" documents, find all "Cartier" documents and from them, find all "watches" documents.

This is my [multi_match](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html) query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "Fred or rose",
      "fields": [
        "name",
        "status",
        "categories.name",
        "brand.name",
        "reference"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

There is my mapping

```
{
  "product": {
    "mappings": {
      "product": {
        "dynamic_date_formats": [],
        "properties": {
          "available": {
            "type": "text"
          },
          "brand": {
            "properties": {
              "available": {
                "type": "text"
              },
              "name": {
                "type": "keyword"
              },
              "shopProductBrands": {
                "properties": {
                  "available": {
                    "type": "text"
                  },
                  "priority": {
                    "type": "integer"
                  },
                  "slug": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                  }
                }
              },
              "slug": {
                "type": "keyword"
              }
            }
          },
          "categories": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
              "available": {
                "type": "text"
              },
              "brand": {
                "properties": {
                  "available": {
                    "type": "text"
                  },
                  "name": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                  },
                  "slug": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                  }
                }
              },
              "name": {
                "type": "keyword"
              },
              "parent": {
                "type": "keyword"
              },
              "slug": {
                "type": "keyword"
              }
            }
          },
          "createdAt": {
            "type": "date",
            "format": "date_time_no_millis"
          },
          "longDescription": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "french_search"
          },
          "name": {
            "type": "text",
            "boost": 15,
            "fields": {
              "raw": {
                "type": "keyword"
              }
            },
            "analyzer": "french_search"
          },
          "purchasePrice": {
            "type": "double"
          },
          "rawPrice": {
            "type": "double"
          },
          "reference": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "boost": 10
          },
          "shortDescription": {
            "type": "text",
            "boost": 3,
            "analyzer": "french_search"
          },
          "slug": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "status": {
            "type": "text"
          },
          "updatedAt": {
            "type": "date",
            "format": "date_time_no_millis"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My search will retrieve all "Gold", "Cartier" and "watches" documents combined.

How can I build a query that follow my rule ?

Thanks

Comment: can you elaborate on why just a simple query string wont due? whats the order meaning? isnt the wanted result `gold AND cartier AND watches` ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that there's an easy solution.  I think the closest you can get is to use [cross_fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html#type-cross-fields) with `"operator": "and"` and only search fields that have the same analyzer.  Can you add "french_search" versions of each of these fields?

> `cross_fields` analyzes the query string into individual terms, then
>   looks for each term in any of the fields, as though they were one big
>   field.

However:

> The cross_field type can only work in term-centric mode on fields that
>   have the same analyzer. ... If there are multiple groups, they are
>   combined with a bool query.

So this query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "type": "cross_fields",
      "query": "gold Cartier watches",
      "fields": [
        "name",
        "status",
        "categories.name",
        "brand.name",
        "reference"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Will become something like this:

```
"query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "gold Cartier watches",
            "fields": ["name"]
          }
        },
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "gold Cartier watches",
            "fields": ["status"]
          }
        },
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "gold Cartier watches",
            "fields": [
              "categories.name",
              "brand.name",
              "reference"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

That query is too loose, but adding `"operator": "and"` or `"minimum_should_match": "100%"` would be too strict.

It's not pretty or efficient, but you could do application-side term parsing and build a boolean query.  Something like this:

```
"query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "gold",
            "fields": [
              "name",
              "status",
              ...
              "reference"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "Cartier",
            "fields": [
              "name",
              "status",
              ...
              "reference"
            ]
          }
        }
        ...
      ]
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this approach 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_boolean_operators

The preferred operators are + (this term must be present) and - (this term must not be present). All other terms are optional. For example, this query:

> quick brown +fox -news

states that:

```
fox must be present
news must not be present
quick and brown are optional — their presence increases the relevance
```

The familiar boolean operators AND, OR and NOT (also written &&, || and !) are also supported but beware that they do not honor the usual precedence rules, so parentheses should be used whenever multiple operators are used together. For instance, the previous query could be rewritten as:

```
((quick AND fox) OR (brown AND fox) OR fox) AND NOT news
```

U can also use boosting for weighing-up result for a specific term https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_boosting